# Right to left scale bar

Tags: qgis, scale-bar, arabic

How to make a right-to-left scale bar in QGIS
[image]

Answer (score 0):

in the layout you have to click on the legend and play with the parameters

[image]

Comment: How to move the labe to the right?

Comment: @Abdelhak Elfengour [2]:   first you have to create the scale in the layout, then select it and finally modify the property parameters (see screenshot). Effectively by default, the scale is filled only to the right
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxR6y.jpg

Comment: @fckaI haven't been able to solve this issue, is there any clear play around for this!